# How do I match the contents of parenthesis in a scala regular expression

Tags: regex, scala

I'm trying to get at the contents of a string like this `(2.2,3.4)` with a scala regular expression to obtain a string like the following `2.2,3.4`

This will get me the string ***with*** parenthesis and all from a line of other text:

```
"""\(.*?\)"""
```

But I can't seem to find a way to get just the contents of the parenthesis.

I've tried:  `"""\((.*?)\)"""  """((.*?))"""` and some other combinations, without luck.

I've used this one in the past in other Java apps:  `\\((.*?)\\)`, which is why I thought the first attempt in the line above `"""\((.*?)\)"""` would work.

For my purposes, this looks something like:

```
var points = "pointA: (2.12, -3.48), pointB: (2.12, -3.48)"
var parenth_contents = """\((.*?)\)""".r;
val center = parenth_contents.findAllIn(points(0));
var cxy = center.next();   
val cx = cxy.split(",")(0).toDouble;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use Lookahead and Lookbehind**

You can use this regex:

```
(?<=\()\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+(?=\))
```

Or, if you don't need precision inside the parentheses:

```
(?<=\()[^)]+(?=\))
```

See [demo 1](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/18) and [demo 2](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/19)

**Explanation**

- The lookbehind `(?<=\()` asserts that what precedes is a `(`
- `\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+` matches the string
- or, in Option 2, `[^)]+` matches any chars that are not a closing parenthesis
- The lookahead `(?=\))` asserts that what follows is a `)`

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: FYI, added a second option and demo. :)

Comment: Thanks, @zx81.  This might not have been clear from my original post, but I need to first find the substring containing the "(something)".  For example, `"pointA: (2.12, -3.48), pointB: (2.12, -3.48)"`  The first regex you suggested doesn't find the "( )".  At least, I can't seem to get it to work...

Comment: Okay Gary, I'm confused. In the question you say you want to find this string: `2.2,3.4`, which is the inside string, so that's what I provided. Now you are saying you'd like something different, but it's still not clear to me what that is. Do you want just the additional parentheses: `(2.12, -3.48)`, or also the words outside: `pointA: (2.12, -3.48)`

Comment: I might be confusing the situation more.  In the example string above `"pointA (2.12, -3.48)"`, I want to find the string `2.12, -3.48`.  Looking back on my original post, I think that is what I said in so many words, but I think adding a larger string example might have clarified things a bit..

Comment: Okay, so get into my demo #2 for instance, and play with the inside of the parentheses. What's highlighted in blue is the match. That's not what you want?

Comment: I'm curious. Is lookahead and lookbehind the only way to do this?

Comment: @wwkudu Most things you can do with lookarounds, you can do with capture groups instead. You just need to specify which capture group to extract.

Answer (score 0):

May be try this out

```
val parenth_contents = "\\(([^)]+)\\)".r
parenth_contents: scala.util.matching.Regex = \(([^)]+)\)

val parenth_contents(r) = "(123, abc)"
r: String = 123, abc
```

Answer (score 0):

A even sample regex for matching all occurrence of both parenthesis itself and content inside the parenthesises.

`(\([^)]+\)+)`

```
1st Capturing Group (\([^)]+\)+)
\( matches the character ( literally (case sensitive)
Match a single character not present in the list below [^)]+
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
) matches the character ) literally (case sensitive)
\)+ matches the character ) literally (case sensitive)
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
Global pattern flags
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
m modifier: multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
```

https://regex101.com/r/MMNRRo/1

Answer (score -1):

`\((.*?)\)` works - you just need to extract the matched group.  The easiest way to do that is to use the `unapplySeq` method of `scala.util.matching.Regex`:

```
scala> val wrapped = raw"\((.*?)\)".r
wrapped: scala.util.matching.Regex = \((.*?)\)

val wrapped(r) = "(123,abc)"
r: String = 123,abc
```

Comment: Thanks, Sean.  I can't quite seem to figure out how to make this work with what I have so far.  I've added some of my code to the original description above.

Comment: @downvoter, would you be willing to explain what I can do to make the answer better?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter. But I guess they might have caught a small typo without bother to say it. They probably had expected something like: scala> val wrapped = "\\\((.*?)\\\)".r