# val a = month(start_date),year(to-date)

Tags: scala

I have a requirement, that I have a string like below input and I want string like below output. can anyone please help me ?

example 1

```
val input = "month(start_date),year(to_date),month(to_date)"

output = "start_date,to-date"
```

example 2

```
input = "abc(start),xyz(end)"

output = "start,end"
```

Comment: is your input character array? like `val input = "month(start_date),year(to_date),month(to_date)"`, What type is it?

Comment: both my input and output are "String"

Comment: you might want to provide input example like `val input = "month(1989),year(2017),month(2017)"`, is that valid??

Comment: no, we are passing column names like start_date, to_date inside month,year functions. so my input  is "month(start_date),year(to_date),month(to_date)"

Comment: Well, only if you provide an example (both `input` and `output`) and update the question, nicer people out there would be able to help you.

Comment: okay, i updated question, Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You need a regex to get the value inside parenthesis

```
val input = "month(start_date),year(to_date),month(to_date)"
val regex = "(?<=\\()[^)]+(?=\\))".r
val output = regex.findAllIn(input).toSet.mkString(",")
```

for regex explanation you can find it here [How do I match the contents of parenthesis in a scala regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564872/how-do-i-match-the-contents-of-parenthesis-in-a-scala-regular-expression)

`toSet` to remove the duplicated
and `mkString` to join the set with comma

Comment: Awesome, working fine, thanks for your help

Comment: Hi,Today I am facing one more issue. My string is like below. Could you please help on this                                                                                         val input = "month(start_date),year(to_date),month(to_date),name,number"               output = "start_date,to_date,name,number"

Comment: I think the regex would still possible but it might be too complex, to keep it simple, may be `split(",")` then do if-else stuff